# Did Ichigo steal Rukia's powers?

Tags: bleach

In the first episodes of *Bleach* does Ichigo steal Rukia's powers?
If so, does it mean all Ichigo's powers were stolen from Rukia, or does Ichigo have his own powers?
Basically, does Ichigo have powers, or is it just like Deku who has obtained them from someone else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did Ichigo originally have Sode no Shiraiyuki?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/102/did-ichigo-originally-have-sode-no-shiraiyuki)

Answer (score 0):

He did steal rukia's power however that doesn't mean that he didn't have powers of his own at all.

It was first revealed when Ichigo was training with Urahara, before he first went to the Soul Society. Old Man Zangetsu told him that Byakuya destroyed the powers Rukia had given him, but failed to destroy Ichigo's own Shinigami powers.